# QCommandLineParser --help and --help-all options are not translated

Tags: c++, qt

I have got this result when using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html#addHelpOption:

```
Использование: ./build/Debug/client/myapp [параметры]

Параметры:
  -h, --help                 Displays help on commandline options.
  --help-all                 Displays help including Qt specific options.
  -v, --version              Отобразить информацию о версии.
```

As one can see, the help entries are not traslated.

I tried to find a more full `qt_ru.qm` file or a `qt_ru.ts` file, but failed. How can be this fixed? Any ideas, please?

**UPDATE (THE SOLUTION)**

For those who are interested. I was inspired by the answer of user **HiFile.app - best file manager** below. I have not found *qt_ru.ts*. Instead, in my OWN myapp_ru.ts file I added the text below, and suddenly it turned out to  be enough to translate the --help and --help-all entries:

```
<context>
    <name>QCommandLineParser</name>
    <message>
        <source>Displays help on commandline options.</source>
        <translation>Вывод справки по параметрам командной строки.</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Displays help including Qt specific options.</source>
        <translation>Вывод справки с особыми параметрами Qt.</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

Comment: What do you mean by entities? `-h, --hellp`? Those MUST NOT be translated! Are you translating scripts which invoke this program? Note this options are used in scripts! Basically your requirement is invalid. Description of this option should be translated.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the descriptions of the help options are not translated, though they should be. I.e., the version description is translated, while the other two options' descriptions are not translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation files (*.ts) are in Qt sources, so you need to install Qt framework with source files. The text you are referring to can be found in `Src/qttranslations/translations/qtbase_ru.ts`. It depends on the Qt version which you are using, but AFAIK it seems to be translated in the latest Qt 6.4. If it is not translated in your Qt version, you can update the *.ts file yourself and convert it to *.qm using Qt Linguist application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how can I find qtbase_ru.ts? I have fedora 35 and there is no such file in the system. Also, why can't I find the .ts file here https://github.com/qt/qtbase ?

Comment: You know, I have added the excerpt from your screen shot to my OWN ts file and it worked. Lol.

Comment: But still maybe you could answer why I cannot find the ts files on the qt's github repo and where can I find them? You somehow found them, as you provide the screen shot.

Comment: @JenyaKh As I wrote: You must have Qt source files installed. Just run Qt Maintenance Tool and opt in for installing Qt source files for your version. In Qt repo, you can find it here https://github.com/qt/qttranslations/blob/dev/translations/qtbase_ru.ts

Comment: If I understand right using Qt Maintenance Tool  is for Windows. I am under Fedora 35 alas. Do you know by chance how this can be installed on Fedora?

Comment: @JenyaKh AFAIK, Qt Maintenance Tool is for all platforms. Just download Qt Online Installer for Linux from https://www.qt.io/download (note: it is a bit cumbersome to find the installer download in Qt webpages, you will probably want to pick open source version... the pages seem to be intentionally confusing probably trying hard to make you decide for paid Qt version...)

Comment: translations are part of qttranslations.git: https://github.com/qt/qttranslations